# Cocoa Swift: Open new instance of the same window

Tags: swift, cocoa, nswindow, xcode10.2

I'm trying to open a new instance of the same window but I have found a way to do it (Xcode X/Cocoa)

This is what I have. I have an NSButton link to IBAction to open a new instance of the same window:

[image]

Any of you knows how can implement something like this?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: How do you open the first instance of the window?

Comment: @Willeke is the window load it thru the window controller

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: @Willeke I have updated the image so you know what I have